# Cygwin Regex Shorthand Character Classes Fail to Match

Tags: regex, sed, cygwin, character-class

I have a file

```
cat /tmp/b
A
Quick
Brown
Fox
Killed
2 Hens
```

If I match on `[0-9]` then I get the expected

```
cat /tmp/b | grep "[0-9]"
2 Hens
```

But if I try to match on the digit character class I get the unexpected

```
cat /tmp/b | grep "\d"
Killed
```

This continues irrespective of what combination of things that I think might work I try

```
cat /tmp/b | grep "\\d"
Killed
cat /tmp/b | grep "\\d"
Killed
cat /tmp/b | grep "\\\\d"
{No matches}
cat /tmp/b | grep "\\\d"
{No matches}
cat /tmp/b | grep "[\\d]"
Killed
cat /tmp/b | grep "[d]"
Killed
cat /tmp/b | grep "[\\\\d]"
Killed
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to get Character Classed working in cygwin sed

**Update**

```
cat /tmp/b | grep [:digit]
Quick
Killed
```

**Update 2**

```
cat /tmp/b | grep [[:digit:]]
2 Hens
```

Comment: Did you check to see if there was more than one grep in your Unix shell path?  Maybe the one you're ending up calling doesn't support that syntax.  If you have regular Windows directories before the Cygwin directories in the path, is there a Windows grep installed on your system?  Try giving the full path to the version of grep that you want.  You might also want to double check that there's not a shell alias defined for "grep".  Oh, also, try using single quotes.

Comment: `which grep` returns `/usr/bin/grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the character class *incorrectly*.  The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) would tell you:

- A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by `[` and `]`
- Certain named classes of characters are predefined within bracket expressions:

  - `[:digit:]` Digits: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

This would imply that in order to match a `[:digit:]` you need to say `[[:digit:]]`.

You'll find:

```
$ cat input | grep -o '[[:digit:]]'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that cygwin uses the [GNU grep regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions), which doesn't support the `\d` abbreviation, but does support `[:digit:]`.  As an aside, I can't explain why you're matching the `d` in the case where you have multiple backslashes preceding the `d` outside of the character class brackets.

Comment: I have colouring on so I can see it is matching the `d`

Comment: As an aside, it's no surprise that all the `[..]` match the `d`, since the `\\`s are just adding `\ ` to the set of characters in the class, but it is a little surprising that \d matches the `d`. For what it's worth, on Mac OS, while \d matches the `d`, none of the quoted variants including the \ match anything.

Comment: Sorry about not assuming you understood that it was matching the `d`. I updated the answer accordingly.